# Why did my views get renamed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior on SQL Server 2012. I have a database with several views, two of them are `CustomerView` and `ShipToAddressView`.

Problem is: Suddenly these views got renamed to `CustomerViewView` and `ShipToAddressViewView`! If I drop and create the views with the correct names, it succeeds, but after a few minutes the rename happens again.

I have no idea why this is happening; this is what I've checked:

- no other users are renaming those views;
- there are no jobs in SQL Server Agent renaming those views;
- there are no triggers renaming those views.

What else could it be?

Comment: Nothing renames view in SQL Server, except user code. Have a look at the default trace.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have no experience on running traces, how can I do that?

Comment: redgate has a free ebook on sql server profiler by Brad M McGehee http://www.red-gate.com/library/mastering-sql-server-profiler and mssqltips has a good intro to running a trace in profiler: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3500/introduction-to-sql-server-profiler/

Comment: If you have any stored procedures, examine the code for each of them. It is not unheard of to include unwanted statements at the end of a procedure by omitting a GO batch separator. I most often see procedures that end with a GRANT EXECUTE statement.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like it was some long-running transactions involving those views, which when rolling back somehow reverted back their names to the name used when creating them, i.e. the ones ending in `ViewView` (which was a typo in the create statement) then renamed to the correct name while some transactions were already started, and possibly renamed back on rollback.